# Unable to create external link to javascript:void();

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, menu-item

While writing a post on [menu items without an actual link](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/menu-item-without-link), I stumbled upon a strange behavior in Joomla 3.3.3:

I wanted to point out that an `<a>` tag linking to `"#"` might cause the page to scroll to the top when clicked, and that it might be better to use `javascript:void();` in the link field for the `External URL` menu item. ([This article](http://paintincode.blogspot.com/2012/03/dont-use-to-create-empty-links.html) explains why.)

I used to do this myself, but now I discovered that in Joomla 3.3.3, it refuses to save if the link field contains `javascript:void();`. Take a look at this screenshot (before and after hitting the "Save" button):

[image: Before and after Save]

I just tested it on an older Joomla version (3.0.3), and I could still use `javascript:void();` in the link field.

Is this a bug in newer versions of Joomla, or was it decided that linking to javascript is not allowed anymore, somewhere between J3.0.3 and J.3.3.3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was actually a bug that it worked (or to be more specific a security issue). The current behaviour is correct.

References:

[Menu item type of External URL can not be saved with javascript:void()](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/actio/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=32572&start=7925)

[How to let menu item execute Javascript in Joomla 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313017/how-to-let-menu-item-execute-javascript-in-joomla-3-2)

Comment: OK, that explains it.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Valentin's answer, [this is how to add javascript code](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/actio/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=32572&start=7925) to a menu item:

- Create a custom link menu item
- Add  `#` in the link field
- Handle the click event by adding javascript elsewhere on the page (e.g. in the footer).

Example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
  $(".menuitemclass").click(function () {
    //your javascript function;     
  });
});
```